# Representing arbitrarily long categorical array data in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

Lets say that I have the user data that I want to "vectorize" for a machine learning task. It comes in the following format:

```
{
  subjects: [String (subject id)],
  education: [
    school: String (school id),
    concentration: String (conc. id),
    degree: String (degree id)
  ],
  age: Integer,
  gender: String
}
```

Data like age and gender I would represent as integers and binary, respectively (0 for women, 1 for men).

If a user were to have a single subject, I could possibly use one-hot encoding to represent it. However, consider the following:

- The number of subjects could be changing (i.e. subjects added/removed). This would mean that the length of the vector in one-hot encoding would change.
- Users can have an arbitrary number of subjects.

The same goes for education records. A user can have an arbitrary number of education records.

So my question is: what is the best way to represent categorical data like this where a user can have an arbitrary amount of it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first, you should know all the possible subjects beforehand.
second, for each subject create a feature like this:

```
subj1 subj2 .... subj1000
0       1             0
```

here user doesn't have subj1 and subj1000 but has subj2.

For  subjects that you may see in future without knowing beforehand, you can just ignore them.

As @Anony-Mousse said this is like the Bag of Words model in text processing.

Comment: Thats what I meant by one-hot encoding. For an array of subjects, could I do something like this (as an example with a user who has 3 subjects):

`0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1`

Comment: Could I use feature hashing?

Comment: Yes you can use feature hashing as in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html

Comment: Remember that for all users the feature set should be the same so you need to list all subjects and then build the one-hot encoding.

Comment: Ok. What would you recommend for the situation where new subjects are added (subjects are referenced by ids)? The way I think of one-hot encoding is that you are representing a categorical value as a basis vector in `N` dimensional vector space. Adding a new subject would be the equivalent to representing subjects in `N+1` dimensions, meaning that the length of the vector representing the user increases by 1, so wouldn't I need to retrain the dataset?

Comment: If the dataset is changing over time and new subjects are added, you could ignore them first and classify using the subjects already in the system. You can retrain the classifyer periodically to include new subjects.